# Angular 6 - Expansion Panel throws ERROR Error: "[object Object]"

Tags: angular, angular-material

i have a question about using the `<mat-expansion-panel>` in my app ([Offical documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/overview)). `ERROR Error: "[object Object]"` is the only error which is thrown in the console. Like mentioned in the documentation I configured my `app.module.ts` like this:

```
import { MatExpansionModule } from '@angular/material/expansion';

...

imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    OverlayModule,
    MatExpansionModule, <<<
    routing
],
```

In my package.json this the current entry for angular materials:

```
"@angular/material": "^6.4.6",
```

The code in my component is taken right from the example:

```
<mat-expansion-panel>
  <mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <mat-panel-title>
      This is the expansion title
    </mat-panel-title>
    <mat-panel-description>
      This is a summary of the content
    </mat-panel-description>
  </mat-expansion-panel-header>

  <p>This is the primary content of the panel.</p>

</mat-expansion-panel>
```

Do I have to include something else or do I have to configure the component somehow?

**Edit:**

Like requested here is the detailed error:

[image: error]

Comment: Any file name or line number on the error?

Comment: I update my question accordingly

Comment: I'm getting the same error when trying to inject the `MatDialog` service into one of my components. Really weird

Answer (score 0):

You must add `BrowserAnimationsModule` to your app.module.

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
  ...

imports: [
    ...
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ...
  ]

})
```

Actually if you debug your Angular app with Chrome you get a better output on console.